# use NSString in other method?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, global-variables

It's really embarrassing but i stuck on it for two hours of trial and error.

I declared an NSString in the interface as:

```
NSString *testString;
```

Then i made a property and synthesized it. I allocate it in viewDidLoad with:

```
testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"thats my value: %i", row];
```

If i want to get the value of the string in another method it always return (null).
So the string is empty, but why? how do i make it accessible for every function inside of one class? So i don't want to make a global var just a "global variable inside the class"

It's really confusing because as long as i code i never ran into this problem :(

thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 3):

In your interface, declare the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSString *testString;
```

In the implementation, synthesize it:

```
@synthesize testString;
```

In the implementation, add a release to the `-dealloc` method:

```
[self.testString release];
```

In `-viewDidLoad`, access the property:

```
self.testString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"that's my value: %i", row] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use

```
self.testString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my value: %i",row];
```

That way you don't need to worry about releasing it.

Also make sure you always use "self".

Comment: Thanks!
ANd what is if i want to declare a nsstring inside viewcontroller1 and want to use it in viewcontroller to?

I took the way with appDelegate.viewcontroller1.testString but that returns also (null) :(

Comment: Is your appDelegate or viewController null too?

Comment: Just add a breakpoint at that point and hover your pointer over them

Comment: no everything here should be okay.
(it shows all init'ed objects and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to retain your string in viewDidLoad. but if it will work for you, don't forget to release it one more time

Answer (score 0):

All other answers have you directly or indirectly `retain`ing testString.  However since you get testString with an `alloc` and an `init`, it is already owned by you without needing to be `retain`ed again.

I'm thinking your problem has to do with something else.  You are either prematurely releasing `testString` in some method, or your `viewDidLoad` did not get called when you were trying to access your `testString` in other methods.

In order for you to use a variable defined in your implementation, you don't have to declare it a `@property` and `@synthesize` it.  Those can help, but you don't have to have them.  You may have to show us more code if this problem doesn't go away.